# how to use inline style within ng-class in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm in a situation where I want to apply an inline style to a DOM element based in a flag that I have defined in a controller. The reason behind this is that I cannot change the existing CSS used in the view, nor extend it.

That said, here is my current view code:

```
  <label class="control-label" ng-class="{'margin-left:100px' : is_modal}">Hello</label>
```

is_modal is just a flag that I switch to true/false in the controller when needed.

The above code is not working, I've also tried:

```
  <label class="control-label" ng-class="{'style=margin-left:100px' : is_modal}">Hello</label>
```

But does not work either. Anybody knows if this is possible? To define inline-styles?

Another option would be ng-style, but I can't seem to bind my controller flag is_modal to the ng-style, since it does not allow to ask for conditions as ng-class does...

Thanks
Alejandro

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're looking for an inline solution then this particular solution might work for you:

```
  <label class="control-label" ng-style="is_modal && {'margin-left': '100px'}">Hello</label>
```

but if you want to have a more consistent and maintainable solution with a complex set of conditions to append with your styling then I suggest you create a scope function that you may place in your `ng-class` or `ng-style` directive.

e.g.

**HTML**

```
<label class="control-label" ng-style="getStyle(is_modal)">Hello</label>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$scope.getStyle = function(is_modal) {
  if(is_modal) {
    return {
       'margin-left': '100px'
    }
  }
};
```

See this [EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/R8Zc9RbyqUXk1bxU1ofx?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ng-style` directive:

```
<label class="control-label" ng-style="is_modal && {margin-left:'100px'}">Hello</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

See this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/kokoqayu/1/edit)

Create a function to evaluate `isModal` and return the correct styles, like:

```
  $scope.isModel = true; // or whatever

  $scope.labelStyle = function() {
    if ($scope.isModel) {
      return {
        'margin-left': '100px'
      }
    }
  }
```

And then your markup would look like:

```
<label ng-style="labelStyle()">Hello</label>
```

Comment: This is a good answer Tom, thank you, but since ryeballar answer is more complete, he gets the correct answer, I'll upvote your one too for pointing in the right direction too, thanks!